# Anything Slider Nested Example

Tags: nested, anythingslider

I've been trying to find an example of a slider-within-a-slider (nested) using Anything Slider.

So far all the old examples on stackoverflow have linked to jsfiddle examples that no longer seem to work: jsfiddle.net/Mottie/S8Je5/217/

Does anyone have any working examples of nesting that they can share with the community?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! SO is not a code sharing website. For more information on the type of questions you can ask, see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). For help on writing good questions, please check out [Jon Skeet's blog](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: Here's an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/S8Je5/295/).